# Rename a Custom Column in Posts and Custom Post Types Admin Screen

Tags: php, wordpress

i want to rename a column (tags) of Posts in admin panel.

```
**title      author     categories     comments     date       tags**
title1       admin      cat            1            9-9-14     php,wordpress
title2       admin      cat            2            9-6-14     php
```

i want to change tags column with named keywords like below:

```
**title      author     categories     comments     date       keywords**
 title1       admin      cat            1            9-9-14     php,wordpress
 title2       admin      cat            2            9-6-14     php
```

how can i do it?

Comment: now see again my question...

Answer (score 2):

Use the filter [`manage_edit-{post_type}_columns`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/manage_edit-post_type_columns):

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-post_columns', 'so_25737839' );

function so_25737839( $columns ) 
{
    $columns['tags'] = 'Keywords';
    return $columns;
}
```